# how to display display checkbox with dropdown menu in column header DataGrid mui with react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

currently I am working with mui datagrid component i have read document for display checkbox header with menulist.
I have pass props as checkboxSelection it display checkbox but i don't how to create menu with it

I have also tried passing props as

```
components={{
            Toolbar: CustomToolbar,
          }}
```

but it display DataGridProps.d.ts(68, 8): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.

Thank you in advance.

i did attached screenshot [image]

Comment: It would be better if you provide a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example